# Is python `Scitools` still active, including `Easyviz`, or is there an alternative?

Tags: python, scientific-computing

I was reading Peter Langtangen's book on scientific computing and he advocates using `Scitools` and the `Easyviz` package to facilitate plotting. I checked the [Scitools](https://github.com/hplgit/scitools) git repository, but it looks like no one has made any updates in like 2 years. I was wondering whether this project was still under active development, or can someone suggest an alternative? Seems nice to be able to abstract away the backend for the plotting in favor of a consistent grammar for the plots.

Comment: There hasn't been an issue closed since March 2015 :-(  Otoh, of it is working & doing what you want, then use it; if not, consider forking it.  Can you not contact the contributors, or post an "is this project still alive?" issue?